# how to make use of Python scalars correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, scalar

```
>>> numpy.sin(range(11))
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025
   -0.95892427, -0.2794155 ,  0.6569866 ,  0.98935825,  0.4121184
   -0.54402111])
>>> numpy.array(range(11))*2
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]) 
>>> str(numpy.array(range(11))... )
'[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]'
```

how can I get ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'] with the concept of python scalars such as numpy.sin(range(11)) or numpy.array(range(11))*2?

I can do that with following:

```
>>> s=[]
>>> [s.append(str(i)) for i in range(11)]
>>> s
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

>>> str(numpy.array(range(11)))
'[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]'
```

what I want is ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'] , not '[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]' .

It gets the string array with the concept of list comprehension, how can get the work done by the concept--python scalars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> a.astype(str)
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
#Python2
map(str, range(11))

#Python3
list(map(str, range(11)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a bit confusing.

`Python` does not have scalars.  Its basic objects are numbers, strings, and lists.  And the lists may be lists of string, lists of numbers, or lists of mixtures.

`numpy` builds on `Python` by adding the concept of a multidimensional array.  Usually the elements of those arrays are numbers.  A `numpy` array may contain single number (with 0 dimensions).  `Numpy` docs distinguish between such an array and a 'plain' Python number by calling the latter a 'scalar'.

But what you really seem to be asking about is a method of displaying a numpy array.

```
In [156]: a=np.arange(10)   # a numpy array of integers

In [157]: str(a)
Out[157]: '[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]'  # a string representation of that array

In [158]: a.tolist()
Out[158]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # a list of numbers

In [159]: str(a.tolist())
Out[159]: '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'  # a string representation of that list

In [160]: [str(i) for i in a]
Out[160]: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] # a list of strings

In [161]: ', '.join(_)
Out[161]: '0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'  # join the strings into one

In [169]: a.astype(str)
Out[169]:  array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], dtype='|S24')
# an array of strings
```

Don't confuse how an array (or any Python objected) is displayed (converted to a string) with the nature of the array.  And when dealing with a composite object like an array or list, there is a difference between how you represent the object as a whole, and how its elements are represented.

---

In your example

```
>>> s=[]
>>> [s.append(str(i)) for i in range(11)]
```

You don't need the append.

```
s = [str(i) for i in range(11)]
```

automatically builds the list.  A list comprehension is, in effect, a compact and fast version of:

```
s = []
for i in range(11):
    s.append(str(i))
```

`map` also works, but the Python developers encourage us to use the comprehensions.